# Фильтрация datagridview с помощью radiobutton

Tags: c#, winforms, radiobutton

Пытаюсь сделать фильтрацию данных по нескольким параметрам с помощью radiobutton, которые сгруппированы в groupBox. Таких groupBox у меня три. Дело в том, что при выборе нескольких radiobutton в разных groupBox фильтрация происходит только по последнему выбранному параметру.

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала сделан поиск "між 180 та 190", потом "між 50 та 60". При этом первый параметр "між 180 та 190" сбросился.

Как сделать так, чтоб второй поиск осуществлялся на основе тех строк, которые остались после первого поиска?

Вот мой код:

```
        private void btn_findFuDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            if (rb_Week.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if ((listFuShow[i].DatetimeFuShow.DayOfYear - 1) / 7 + 1 == (dt.DayOfYear - 1) / 7 + 1)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            if (rb_Month.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listFuShow[i].DatetimeFuShow.Month == dt.Month)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            if (rb_Year.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listFuShow[i].DatetimeFuShow.Year == dt.Year)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void btn_findFuGrowth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(rb_170.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listFuShow[i].GrowthFuModel <170)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            if(rb_170_180.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listFuShow[i].GrowthFuModel >= 170 && listFuShow[i].GrowthFuModel<180)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            if(rb_180_190.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listFuShow[i].GrowthFuModel >= 180 && listFuShow[i].GrowthFuModel < 190)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            if (rb_190.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listFuShow[i].GrowthFuModel > 190)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void btn_findWeight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rb_40.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listFuShow[i].WeightFuModel < 40)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            if (rb_40_50.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listFuShow[i].WeightFuModel >= 40 && listFuShow[i].WeightFuModel < 50)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            if (rb_50_60.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listFuShow[i].WeightFuModel >= 50 && listFuShow[i].WeightFuModel < 60)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }

            if (rb_60.Checked)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (listFuShow[i].WeightFuModel > 60)
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    else
                        dgwFutureShows.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

```
class FuShow //у вас должен быть подобный класс, только с большим числом полей
{
    public DateTime DatetimeFuShow;
    public int GrowthFuModel;
    public int WeightFuModel;
}
//List<FuShow> listFuShow = new List<FuShow>(); //как и этот список, который вы биндите
//
Predicate<int> zrist_selected;
Predicate<int> vaga_selected;
Predicate<DateTime> data_selected;
//
bool do_170(int val) => val < 170;
bool mizh_170_ta_180(int val) => val >= 170 && val < 180;
bool mizh_180_ta_190(int val) => val >= 180 && val < 190;
bool bilshe_190(int val) => val >= 190;
//
bool do_40(int val) => val < 40;
bool mizh_40_ta_50(int val) => val >= 40 && val < 50;
bool mizh_50_ta_60(int val) => val >= 50 && val < 60;
bool bilshe_60(int val) => val >= 60;
//
bool week(DateTime dt) => ((dt.DayOfYear - 1) / 7 + 1 == (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear - 1) / 7 + 1);
bool month(DateTime dt) => dt.Month == DateTime.Now.Month;
bool year(DateTime dt) => dt.Year == DateTime.Now.Year;
//
private void btn_findFuDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rb_Week.Checked) data_selected = week;
    else if (rb_Month.Checked) data_selected = month;
    else if (rb_Year.Checked) data_selected = year;
    else data_selected = null;
    Update();
}
private void btn_findFuGrowth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rb_170.Checked) zrist_selected = do_170;
    else if (rb_170_180.Checked) zrist_selected = mizh_170_ta_180;
    else if (rb_180_190.Checked) zrist_selected = mizh_180_ta_190;
    else if (rb_190.Checked) zrist_selected = bilshe_190;
    else zrist_selected = null;
    Update();
}
private void btn_findWeight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rb_40.Checked) vaga_selected = do_40;
    else if (rb_40_50.Checked) vaga_selected = mizh_40_ta_50;
    else if (rb_50_60.Checked) vaga_selected = mizh_50_ta_60;
    else if (rb_60.Checked) vaga_selected = bilshe_60;
    else vaga_selected = null;
    Update();
}
void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgwFutureShows.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var row = dgwFutureShows.Rows[i];
        FuShow item = row.DataBoundItem as FuShow;
        if (item == null) row.Visible = true; //если 
        else
        {
            row.Visible = //отображать если
                (data_selected?.Invoke(item.DatetimeFuShow) ?? true) && //если выставлен предикат и условия подходят, если предикат не выставлен - не фильтруется
                (zrist_selected?.Invoke(item.GrowthFuModel) ?? true) && //..
                (vaga_selected?.Invoke(item.WeightFuModel) ?? true); //..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Юлия работает без косяков? Сам не проверял.